# Using json object in symfony2 not allowed?

Tags: json, symfony, twitter

I have retrieved a twitter feed in json format, and when I run this block right on my apacheserver it works fine and delivers a nice table with the twitter feeds.

However, when placed inside a symfony2 controller, it breaks with this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$retweeted_status in /var/www/cloudsign_beta/src/BizTV/ArchiveBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 76
```

The code:

```
public function TwitterAction($rts, $name, $count)
{

    if ($rts=='on') {
        $rts = 'true';
    }
    else {
        $rts = 'false';
    }

    if ($name=='') {
        //$name = 'warpnine'; 
        //Bazinga!
    }

    if ($count=='') {
        $count = 10;
    }

    $variable = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_rts='.$rts.'&screen_name='.$name.'&count='.$count);
    $tws = json_decode($variable);

    if (isset($tws)) {
        $r = '<table>';
            foreach ($tws as $tw){
                if ($tw->retweeted_status->id > 0) {
                    $r .='<tr><td class="twitter_td"><img src="'.$tw->retweeted_status->user->profile_image_url.'" class="twitter_img"></td><td>'.
                                $tw->retweeted_status->user->name.
                                ' <i>@'.$tw->retweeted_status->user->screen_name.'</i><br>'.
                                $tw->text.'</td></tr>';
                } else {
                    $r .= '<tr><td class="twitter_td"><img src="'.$tw->user->profile_image_url.'" class="twitter_img"></td><td>'.
                                $tw->user->name.
                                ' <i>@'.$tw->user->screen_name.'</i><br>'.
                                $tw->text.'</td></tr>';
                }
            }
        $r .= '</table>';
    }
    else {
        $r = "Hittade ingen twitterfeed för <strong>$name</strong>";
    }

    return new Response($r);

}
```

Here is a var_dump of the $tw first iteration

```
object(stdClass)#878 (19) { ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Tue Jan 15 15:48:55 +0000 2013" ["id"]=> int(291210363318435841) ["id_str"]=> string(18) "291210363318435841" ["text"]=> string(97) "Looking forward to speaking at Washington and Lee University in Lexington, Virginia, later today!" ["source"]=> string(63) "TweetDeck" ["truncated"]=> bool(false) ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_user_id_str"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=> NULL ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#875 (38) { ["id"]=> int(287413569) ["id_str"]=> string(9) "287413569" ["name"]=> string(8) "Ron Paul" ["screen_name"]=> string(7) "RonPaul" ["location"]=> string(27) "Clute, TX / Washington D.C." ["url"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(99) "Former Congressman from Texas, Chairman of Campaign for Liberty, and Champion of the Constitution. " ["protected"]=> bool(false) ["followers_count"]=> int(387763) ["friends_count"]=> int(159) ["listed_count"]=> int(4852) ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Sun Apr 24 23:20:55 +0000 2011" ["favourites_count"]=> int(1) ["utc_offset"]=> int(-18000) ["time_zone"]=> string(26) "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" ["geo_enabled"]=> bool(false) ["verified"]=> bool(true) ["statuses_count"]=> int(976) ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" ["contributors_enabled"]=> bool(false) ["is_translator"]=> bool(false) ["profile_background_color"]=> string(6) "ED1D24" ["profile_background_image_url"]=> string(93) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/758570925/9c556d05e88c52861e85356d0cbf1a4c.jpeg" ["profile_background_image_url_https"]=> string(95) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/758570925/9c556d05e88c52861e85356d0cbf1a4c.jpeg" ["profile_background_tile"]=> bool(false) ["profile_image_url"]=> string(90) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3066929869/81d574c68b91e40db69992c0afd34d29_normal.jpeg" ["profile_image_url_https"]=> string(92) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3066929869/81d574c68b91e40db69992c0afd34d29_normal.jpeg" ["profile_banner_url"]=> string(58) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_banners/287413569/1357674836" ["profile_link_color"]=> string(6) "DE0A22" ["profile_sidebar_border_color"]=> string(6) "FFFFFF" ["profile_sidebar_fill_color"]=> string(6) "FFFFFF" ["profile_text_color"]=> string(6) "333333" ["profile_use_background_image"]=> bool(true) ["default_profile"]=> bool(false) ["default_profile_image"]=> bool(false) ["following"]=> NULL ["follow_request_sent"]=> NULL ["notifications"]=> NULL } ["geo"]=> NULL ["coordinates"]=> NULL ["place"]=> NULL ["contributors"]=> NULL ["retweet_count"]=> int(96) ["favorited"]=> bool(false) ["retweeted"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: What does `$tw` look like? Can you `var_dump` a piece of it? Also, why are you using version 1 of the API when it's to be removed soon?

Comment: You should not be building HTML in the controller, that logic should go in the view.

Comment: var_dump added above. I will check with my API guy about that version update, thanks. As for controller/view logic, this is just a response to an ajax call and I was too lazy to set up a twig for it =)

Comment: OK I see now that I was looking for a property that in fact didn't exist, I guess my localhost was not as strict on the NOTICE as symfony2 is, thus it seemed to work fine on the localhost. This is probably however related to that outdated API usage since this variable didn't exist. We'll look into that, thanks for leading me right =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice: Undefined property means that 'retweeted_status' does not exists in this case (for this item in the loop). As mentioned in the comments, sf2 has strict mode on bydefault (a good thing to improve code).

Try to add something like

```
if(isset($tw->retweeted_status) { }
```

so your code would look like

```
foreach ($tws as $tw){
    if(isset($tw->retweeted_status) {
            if ($tw->retweeted_status->id > 0) {
                $r .='<tr><td class="twitter_td"><img src="'.$tw->retweeted_status->user->profile_image_url.'" class="twitter_img"></td><td>'.
                            $tw->retweeted_status->user->name.
                            ' <i>@'.$tw->retweeted_status->user->screen_name.'</i><br>'.
                            $tw->text.'</td></tr>';
            } else {
                $r .= '<tr><td class="twitter_td"><img src="'.$tw->user->profile_image_url.'" class="twitter_img"></td><td>'.
                            $tw->user->name.
                            ' <i>@'.$tw->user->screen_name.'</i><br>'.
                            $tw->text.'</td></tr>';
            }
    }
}
```